# What is a working VNC client for latest Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, vnc

From my Xubuntu desktop, I'm trying to VNC into a raspberry pi. I can connect from my android tablet to Pi and operate it just fine so I know the server is up and running, when I use the same server IP and credentials on various Linux VNC clients, it fails. So far I've tried:

**Remmenia**: "Unknown authentication scheme from server."

**KRDC**: Logs in, but I get a blue screen/wallpaper, no icons, no control.

**Vinagre**: "connection to host closed"

**XtightVNCviewer**: "No configured security type is supported by 3.3 VNC Viewer"

Any other VNC clients I can try? Or what can I do to fix one of the above clients.
The VNC server running on the Pi is whatever is currently shipped with Raspbian, I think it might be TightVNCServer.

Comment: remmina works but you have to change the VNC security settings on the raspberry pi from "UNIX password" to "VNC password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Jean-Marie's comment. Going into the settings for the VNC server and changing it from the default Unix username and password to VNC password makes it work with more VNC clients.